# Where can I download the jar for org.apache.http package?

Tags: java, apache, jar

I want the **jar file** for `org.apache.http` package but I am not able to find it,can anyone let me know from where can I download it?

I was not able to find the jar even in Apache site as well **findjar.co** site.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[Apache HttpCore](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

Updated with new link

Comment: i have got few 4.0.1 zip data,but the jar org.apache.http required is not there.

Comment: Did you download HttpCore (both HttpClient and HttpCore are on the same download page)?  The zip file is httpcomponents-core-4.0.1-bin.zip.  It contains lib/httpcore-4.0.1.jar which has the org.apache.http.* classes.

Comment: the link for the android lib is death, is there a alternative ?

Answer (score 12):

You can add `org.apache.http` by using below code in `app:Build gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

At the Maven repo, there are samples to add the dependency in maven, sbt, gradle, etc.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.11

ie for Maven, you just create a project, for example

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4
```

then look at the pom.xml, then at the library at the dependencies xml element:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

For sbt do something like

```
sbt new scala/hello-world.g8
```

then edit the build.sbt to add the library

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore" % "4.4.11"
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadservletapijar.htm

Download servlet-api.jar 
That has all the  files below:

```
META-INF/LICENSE
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/NOTICE
javax.servlet.Async

Context.class
javax.servlet.AsyncEvent.class
javax.servlet.AsyncListener.class
javax.servlet.DispatcherType.class
javax.servlet.Filter.class
javax.servlet.FilterChain.class
javax.servlet.FilterConfig.class
javax.servlet.FilterRegistration.class
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.class
javax.servlet.HttpConstraintElement.class
javax.servlet.HttpMethodConstraintElement.class
javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement.class
javax.servlet.Registration.class
javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.class
javax.servlet.Servlet.class
javax.servlet.ServletConfig.class
javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer.class
javax.servlet.ServletContext.class
javax.servlet.ServletContextAttributeEvent.class
javax.servlet.ServletContextAttributeListener.class
javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent.class
javax.servlet.ServletContextListener.class
javax.servlet.ServletException.class
javax.servlet.ServletInputStream.class
javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream.class
javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.class
javax.servlet.ServletRequest.class
javax.servlet.ServletRequestAttributeEvent.class
javax.servlet.ServletRequestAttributeListener.class
javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent.class
javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener.class
javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.class
javax.servlet.ServletResponse.class
javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.class
javax.servlet.ServletSecurityElement.class
javax.servlet.SessionCookieConfig.class
javax.servlet.SessionTrackingMode.class
javax.servlet.SingleThreadModel.class
javax.servlet.UnavailableException.class
javax.servlet.annotation.HandlesTypes.class
javax.servlet.annotation.HttpConstraint.class
javax.servlet.annotation.HttpMethodConstraint.class
javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig.class
javax.servlet.annotation.ServletSecurity.class
javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter.class
javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam.class
javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener.class
javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet.class
javax.servlet.descriptor.JspConfigDescriptor.class
javax.servlet.descriptor.JspPropertyGroupDescriptor.class
javax.servlet.descriptor.TaglibDescriptor.class
javax.servlet.http.Cookie.class
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.class
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.class
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.class
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.class
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.class
javax.servlet.http.HttpSession.class
javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionActivationListener.class
javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionAttributeListener.class
javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingEvent.class
javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingListener.class
javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionContext.class
javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent.class
javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener.class
javax.servlet.http.HttpUtils.class
javax.servlet.http.NoBodyOutputStream.class
javax.servlet.http.NoBodyResponse.class
javax.servlet.http.Part.class
javax/servlet/LocalStrings.properties
javax/servlet/http/LocalStrings.properties
javax/servlet/resources/XMLSchema.dtd
javax/servlet/resources/datatypes.dtd
javax/servlet/resources/j2ee_1_4.xsd
javax/servlet/resources/j2ee_web_services_1_1.xsd
javax/servlet/resources/j2ee_web_services_client_1_1.xsd
javax/servlet/resources/javaee_5.xsd
javax/servlet/resources/javaee_6.xsd
javax/servlet/resources/javaee_web_services_1_2.xsd
javax/servlet/resources/javaee_web_services_1_3.xsd
javax/servlet/resources/javaee_web_services_client_1_2.xsd
javax/servlet/resources/javaee_web_services_client_1_3.xsd
javax/servlet/resources/web-app_2_2.dtd
javax/servlet/resources/web-app_2_3.dtd
javax/servlet/resources/web-app_2_4.xsd
javax/servlet/resources/web-app_2_5.xsd
javax/servlet/resources/web-app_3_0.xsd
javax/servlet/resources/web-common_3_0.xsd
javax/servlet/resources/web-fragment_3_0.xsd
javax/servlet/resources/xml.xsd
```

Answer (score 1):

Use libraries
https://jar-download.com/maven-repository-class-search.php?search_box=org.apache.http.entity.mime
Download the library and put it in your project

Answer (score 0):

You need httpclient.jar and httpcore.jar. You can download them from here.

http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/