# How to use a third-party component in a modular way in Liferay?

Tags: gradle, liferay, osgi

I wrote a Liferay 7 module that uses [org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html).

So I downloaded the [httpclient-osgi JAR](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi/4.5.3) and put it in `deploy/`, but when I try to start it I get:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient [1088]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.http; version="[4.4.0,4.5.0)"
```

So I searched mvnrepository.com for `org.apache.http`.
PROBLEM: No such component seems to exist.

Do I have no other option than [including the classes inside my Liferay module](https://web.liferay.com/web/user.26526/blog/-/blogs/osgi-module-dependencies)?
Doing so sounds contrary to the OSGi principles: if my 100 Liferay modules use httpclient then including httpclient in each of them does not sound very modular.

Am I thinking the wrong way?
How to use a third-party component in a modular way in Liferay?

Comment: [org.apache.http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932321/where-can-i-download-the-jar-for-org-apache-http-package)

Comment: @LazerBanana: Your link directs to a question whose accepted answer is a link that redirects to the list of all software Apache has ever released: https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/ By the way, most of the JARs in that tree are probably not OSGi components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are searching for is a package name not a jar name.
Apache httpclient needs httpcore.

These bundles are known to work well together:

```
mvn:org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi/4.5.3
mvn:org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore-osgi/4.4.6
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi/4.5.3
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore-osgi/4.4.6